# How to add a shortcode value to another shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I need to insert an ACF value to another shortcode [other_shortcode value="[acf field="field_name"]"]. I know it doesn't work, I think I need to tweak the "other_shortcode" so I can pass the value of ACF that way [other_shortcode value="acf_value"]. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
if( get_field('fieldname')) {
 $field1 = get_field('field_name'); 
echo do_shortcode('
 <div> [other_shortcode title="' . $field1 . '"][/other_shortcode] </div> ' );
 
}?>
```

Look this code maybe you can do it